# Session Attribute Not getting updated in .gsp Page after Ajax Call

Tags: java, ajax, grails, session-variables

I am using session attributes in my .gsp page like below:

```
<g:set var="maxValue" value="${session?.MY_VAR}"/>
```

I am making an AJax call from Javascript to the Groovy controller ( MyController.groovy ) and setting it like below:

session.setAttribute("MY_VAR", "abc");

After Ajax call returns back to the GSP. The value of session variable is not updated. It still stores the old value from the previous load.

Any ideas on how to solve this ?

Comment: post the code that updates your session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your GSP is generated on the server and the resulting HTML is sent to the browser. Your Ajax call does not force a page refresh, so the GSP along with the line below is not reevaluated and the variable `maxValue` is not changed.

```
<g:set var="maxValue" value="${session?.MY_VAR}"/>
```

You should consider `render as JSON` in your controller to return `maxValue` and using JavaScript to update the DOM after the Ajax response is received. See [render](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html) for more info.